# How to stop text from resizing on different resolutions

Tags: html, css, text, resize

when i zoom in or out on my browser or use a different size screen (e.g my laptop) the text scales up and gets all messed up how do i fix this

i have tried multiple different things using the meta veiwport code doesn't work it doesn't change anything if i use position absolute or fixed or relative its all in percentage except the font size which is in pt (dont know if that matters

there is the css

```
.text {
color: white;
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 28%;
top: 8%;
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: arial;
background-color: grey;
width: 70%
```

and here is the html for it

```
<div class="text"> Space is a very cool place but also a very dangerous place to be in from sickening ionizing radiation to the lack of oxygen and the many other dangers that space contains but space also contains many wonders and mysteries waiting to be uncovered. </div>
```

Comment: It will affect the responsiveness. Is that okay?

Comment: sure ill try it

Comment: Try `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: have you tried font-size: 4vw; or in rem unit